# How to make spaces between words using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, winforms, filestream

I need to build a table inside a file.txt. Actually, I have some Ideas on how build it, but I'm not so sure. I have some fields and it's values I just need to build a table using these fields' name and it's values, like:

```
========================================
ID     MATRICULATION     NAME
2      696969            Jose
4      969696            Maria
5      123456            Eminem
15     123412            Ghaleon
```

How may I do it? I guess it's using `StreamWriter` but I don't know how to make the spaces because just using spacebar does not work.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, what your input is, or what you've actually tried. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list. `StreamWriter` really *does* write spaces... but if you're viewing a file in a proportional font, it's hard to make things line up, if that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I just want to build something like a `table´ but inside a file.txt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use format when writing string to file:

```
writer.WriteLine("{0,-10}{1,-15}{2}", id, matriculation, name);
```

Syntax of format is [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx):

```
{index[,length][:formatString]}
```

*length* is the minimum number of characters in the string representation of the parameter. If positive, the parameter is right-aligned; if negative, it is left-aligned

Comment: What is this `format`? I need to put some `spaces` to order it like  a `table`, you know ? I don't know how to do that, like the spaces that happens when we press `tab` button...

Comment: hey lazyberevosky, is there something like `Text-Align: center` ? Some way to set them all centralized ?

Comment: @Ghaleon You can also use a `\t` to embed a tab character into your text.

Comment: @Ghaleon No, there is no such option. You can pad string to align it `var result = matriculation.PadLeft(matriculation.Length + (20 - matriculation.Length)/2, ' ')`. This code adds spaces before string to align it in the center of 20-char width field

Comment: @lazyberezovsky thanks man ! I'll just make some tests before mark as answer.